# Servicestack as SSRS datasource

Tags: reporting-services, servicestack

I am trying to use servicestack as a datasource for my SSRS report.  Is this possible?  Right now I have a simple operation that takes a date as a parameter, looks like this in C#

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/Reports/SummaryBySymbol/{SummaryDate}", Summary = "Summarizes trades by symbol for a specific date.")]
public class GetTradesGroupedBySymbol : IReturn<TradesGroupedBySymbolResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    [ApiMember(Name = "Summary Date",
        Description = "The date for which the trades will be summarized..",
        DataType = "DateTime",
        IsRequired = true)]
    public DateTime SummaryDate { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TradesGroupedBySymbolResponse
{
    [DataMember] public IList<SymbolSummary> Result { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create a dataset in SSRS using: http://machineName:port/soap11 
as the datasource.

When the dataset asks for a query, I have no idea what to enter as text and the examples [I can find](http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/articles/107070.aspx) always cause the interface to freeze when I hit the 'next' button (so I must assume I entered something incorrectly).

Here is what I tried to enter as the query:

```
<Query>
  <Method Namespace="http://www.company.com/types" Name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbol" />
  <SoapAction>
      http://www.company.com/types/GetTradesGroupedBySymbol
  </SoapAction>
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="SummaryDate" Type="XML"/>
  </Parameters>
  <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True"> 
    GetTradesGroupedBySymbolResponse{}/Result{}/SymbolSummary
  </ElementPath> 
</Query>
```

Here is the wsdl for the service:

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:svc="http://www.company.com/types" xmlns:tns="http://www.company.com/types" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" name="Soap11" targetNamespace="http://www.company.com/types">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
      <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
      <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
      <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
      <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
      <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
      <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
      <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
      <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
      <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
      <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
      <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
      <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="char">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="duration">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
          <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
          <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
      <xs:simpleType name="guid">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.company.com/types" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.company.com/types">
      <xs:complexType name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbol">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SummaryDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbol" nillable="true" type="tns:GetTradesGroupedBySymbol"/>
      <xs:complexType name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbolResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Result" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfSymbolSummary"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbolResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:GetTradesGroupedBySymbolResponse"/>
      <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfSymbolSummary">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SymbolSummary" nillable="true" type="tns:SymbolSummary"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="ArrayOfSymbolSummary" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfSymbolSummary"/>
      <xs:complexType name="SymbolSummary">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BuyQuantityFilled" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BuyTotalValue" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BuyWeightedAveragePrice" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CompanyName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SellQuantityFilled" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SellTotalValue" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SellWeightedAveragePrice" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Ticker" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="SymbolSummary" nillable="true" type="tns:SymbolSummary"/>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbolIn">
    <wsdl:part name="par" element="tns:GetTradesGroupedBySymbol"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbolOut">
    <wsdl:part name="par" element="tns:GetTradesGroupedBySymbolResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ISyncReply">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbol">
      <wsdl:input message="svc:GetTradesGroupedBySymbolIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="svc:GetTradesGroupedBySymbolOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncReply" type="svc:ISyncReply">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetTradesGroupedBySymbol">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.company.com/types/GetTradesGroupedBySymbol" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SyncReply">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncReply" binding="svc:BasicHttpBinding_ISyncReply">
      <soap:address location="http://serverName:port/soap11"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I would expect the query to ask me for a parameter before attempting to run the soapAction (or at least error out), but the interface just locks up and I have to kill Visual Studio.  Any ideas out there as to what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

Modified the above query and wsdl to show latest attempts to get this to work.  VS still freezes.

Comment: When you test the data source does it say successful?

Comment: How does one test an xml datasource?  If by test you mean does the webservice work and return results, then yes.  If you mean something else, please explain.

Comment: When you create a data source in SSRS there is a "Test Connection" button. This will tell us if it is able to establish a connection at all. This has to work before you can run a query.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of visual studio you are using but on VS2017 there is no 'test connection' button for xml datasources (see the link 'I can find' above to see a screenshot of what my connection dialog looks like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem was the long running webservice response causing a connection time out in the wizard and causing the entire VS2017 environment to freeze (not optimal behavior).  Once I created a dummy version of the webservice that responds with the same DTO and couple of dummy rows but that returned in less than a second, everything worked.  The report was generated and I could then go in to the dataset, change the timeout to be 2 minutes and then changed the query to point back to the real web method and it worked as expected.

As a follow up detail, if you are passing a date to ServiceStack, use the 'String' data type (not XML) and ensure that the date format is yyyy-mm-dd (months and days must be padded with zeros if they are single digit values).